# Sonar generates an empty git repository and can't find any source code

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I am trying to integrate Sonar Scanner in my GitLab CI pipeline. GitLab runner running in the same server with Sonar. Once I created sonar with docker-compose I add my GitLab token then I choose repository from UI. It tells to add SONAR_TOKEN variable and SONAR_URL as shown. After adding them finally I push my code to the GitLab.

This my **docker-compose.yml** file for sonar:

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:community
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: ${SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME}
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: ${SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

This is my **gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
default:
  tags:
    - my-custom-tag-1
    - my-custom-tag-2

stages:
  - test

sonarqube-check:
  image:
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: test
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
    SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS: "-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_STRATEGY: "clone" # clone entire repo instead of reusing workspace
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script: 
    - sonar-scanner
  allow_failure: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'
```

This is my **sonar-project.properties** file located in *.sonar*:

```
sonar.projectKey=${SONAR_PROJECT_KEY}
sonar.qualitygate.wait=true
```

I don't know the default behavior but in the gitlab runner logs I've found these lines:

```
INFO: Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/my-project/.git
```

```
INFO: 0 files indexed
```

I've looked [SonarQube GitLab Integration](https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/devops-platform-integration/gitlab-integration/) and this [thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-gitlab-integration/40833) and followed from this medium [post](https://medium.com/@alishayb/quality-assurance-using-sonarqube-gitlab-sonarqube-integration-f6ae61bc49f4)

Comment: Could you try only the sonar without gitlab-ci  ?

Comment: You mean manually ?

Comment: Yes. To validate your credentials and if it is possible the integration with sonarqube https://medium.com/code-to-express/sonarqube-static-code-analysis-8b6ca5226d2b